# References for LWP of a NLS Equation

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

I am studying the LWP of $$i \partial_t \psi + \Delta \psi = \left| \psi \right|^{p-1} \psi + \frac{1}{\left| x \right|^2} \psi$$ in $\mathbb{R}^{1+2}$ given appropriate Cauchy data. It will probably require the use of weighted Sobolev spaces. Does anyone know of a good reference that might help me?

Comment: A google search turns up this article http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00036811.2011.631914#.U58gA_ldXKh , although I don't have full access to it at present.

Comment: @Terry Thanks! I thought it might be known, but I wasn't really sure what to search for. What words did you use to find this paper?

Comment: "NLS" and "inverse square potential".  (I had also tried NLS and "Coulomb potential" but this gave less relevant hits.)